# Помогите построить гистограмму Tableu

Tags: анализ-данных, график, графики

Пытаюсь построить гистограмму распределения количества выживших на Титанике в Tableu (тренировочная задача) по классам кают. Итог должен выглядеть так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как агрегировать данные чтоб такой график построить.

У меня данные по классу (1,2,3) и выжил/не выжил (0 - выжил, 1 - не выжил) переведены в строки.